# How to change the default value of ${project.build.outputDirectory} in Maven?

Tags: maven

I would like to know how to change the default value of ${project.build.outputDirectory} from target/classes to codebase in maven.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

inside the pom.xml within build:

```
<build>
  <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
</build>
```

see http://maven.apache.org/pom.html for even more fun with the pom